# How do i make this work? i keep getting Syntax errors

Tags: python

```
print("welcome to the password reset program")
print("please enter the new password")
input("type your new password")
input("type your new password (8-16 characters)")
password = input("type your new password (8-16 characters)")
    if password == <8
        print("this is too short, rethink, and re-enter your new password...")
    if password == >16
        print("this is too long, rethink, and re-enter your new password...")
    if password == 8-16
        print("this is the correct length, now re-enter to confirm")
password2 = input("re-enter your password")
    if password == password2
        print("your password has been changed")
    if password != password2
        print("this is not the same as your first password")
```

i get the error with " if password == <8 "
can you help me please????

Comment: Check python doc. You have to use `:` after if. Like this`if some_value:`

Comment: You have an `unexpected indent` at the `if password == <8 ` line and you need to add a `:` at the end of the line

Comment: You should think about taking a look at some Python tutorials.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
print("welcome to the password reset program")
print("please enter the new password")
input("type your new password")
input("type your new password (8-16 characters)")
password = input("type your new password (8-16 characters)")
if len(password) <= 8:
    print("this is too short, rethink, and re-enter your new password...")
elif len(password) >= 16:
    print("this is too long, rethink, and re-enter your new password...")
else:
    print("this is the correct length, now re-enter to confirm")
    password2 = input("re-enter your password")
    if password == password2:
        print("your password has been changed")
    else:
        print("this is not the same as your first password")
```

As others have suggested I'd read the documentation on indentation in python as well as how to use if/else.

Comment: I don't mind downvotes but a comment to explain would be appreciated!

Comment: `password >= 16:` is wrong. Also, answers without explanation aren't very useful

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to change it the second time. And I agree about the explanation but most was already said in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

You need to compare the length of password, using `len()`.

You also need to use `<` or `<=` to compare it rather than `==`, and put a colon at the end of the if statement.

So your code would look like:

```
if len(password) <= 8:
    print("this is too short, rethink, and re-enter your new password...")
if len(password) >=16:
    print("this is too long, rethink, and re-enter your new password...")
```

Which you could simplify to

```
if len(password) <= 8 or len(password) >= 16:
    print("Password must be between 8 and 16 characters, enter your new password...")
```

To get the user to re-enter a password, you could loop until their input is valid using `while`:

```
while(len(password) <= 8 or len(password) >= 16):
    print("Password must be between 8 and 16 characters, enter your new password...")
    password=input("type your new password")
```

You could use this again to check the user enters the same password:

```
password2 = input("re-enter your password")
while password2!=password:
     password2=input("this is not the same as your first password")
print("your password has been changed")
```

As other users have mentioned, you should look at hashing:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html

Comment: you are missing a ":" on line 3

Comment: It would also be worth linking or informing the OP about hashing. If they are going to play with passwords they should know about hashing.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no such thing as  'x== < y'. You're looking for 'x <= y'.

Second, as stated in answers before me, you have to add ':' after the if.

You should read the docs.

Answer (score -1):

There is a couple things wrong with your code and I'm guessing you maybe coming from a JavaScript background.

The issues are as follows.

1. You are missing the `:` at the end of your `if` statements.
2. You can't use `== <` or `== >` in Python the correct one to use is `<=` and `>=`.
3. You also have incorrect indentation for your `if` statements.

Updated code below.

```
print("welcome to the password reset program")
print("please enter the new password")
input("type your new password")
input("type your new password (8-16 characters)")
password = input("type your new password (8-16 characters)")
if len(password) <= 8:
    print("this is too short, rethink, and re-enter your new password...")
if len(password) >= 16:
    print("this is too long, rethink, and re-enter your new password...")
if len(password) == (8-16): # is this a range or 8 - 16?
    print("this is the correct length, now re-enter to confirm")
password2 = input("re-enter your password")
if password == password2:
    print("your password has been changed")
if password != password2:
    print("this is not the same as your first password")
```

Don't forget to hash the passwords.https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html

Comment: I'm not sure why I got a down vote for my answer when it is technically correct and answers the users question.

Comment: `(8-16)` is not a range

Comment: I didn't say it was. I made an inline comment asking if that's what the OP was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

1. You need to add `:` after each if, for or while statement.
2. The operators `== <` or `== >` doesnt exist, you can use `=>` or `<=` instead
3. In this line: `if password == 8-16` you can use the operator `in` to evaluate that the variable is in a list, souch as `if len(password) in range(8-16)`

In your case could be

```
if password <= 8
        print("this is too short, rethink, and re-enter your new password...")
    if password >= 16
        print("this is too long, rethink, and re-enter your new password...")
    if len(password) in range(8, 16)
        print("this is the correct length, now re-enter to confirm")
password2 = input("re-enter your password")
    if password == password2
        print("your password has been changed")
    if password != password2
        print("this is not the same as your first password")
```

Comment: The indentation is wrong, you didn't add `:` anywhere, and comparing `password` and integers is meaningless.